# Running Selenium TestNG in command line - nosuchmethod exception

Tags: java, selenium, command-line, path

I'm running testNG testcases in cmd. My batch file is as following:

```
cd C:\..\eclipse-workspace\Project

set ProjectPath=C:\..\eclipse-workspace\Project
set classpath=%ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\test-util\testng\*;%ProjectPath%\test-util\testrail-api\*;%ProjectPath%\test-util\selenium-java-3.5.0\*;%ProjectPath%\test-util\json-simple\*;

java org.testng.TestNG test1.xml

pause
```

The xml file can be read by testNG, but the browser won't open up(I'm running three browsers in parallel, and all three have the same exception). Testcases can be run using EclipseIDE.

The second line of the code throws the exception :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", userDir + prefixPathDriver + chromeDriverExe);
chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
```

The exe path is valid(I can copy the system.out.print to explorer and open the webdriver.exe)

I had a look at the output file and get,

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:329)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
    at utilities.Utilities.getChromeDriver(Utilities.java:129)
    at testcases.EngagementPageSEOFooter.init(EngagementPageSEOFooter.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: While building your project did you make sure all your dependent classes are included? Since that's what the error reads.

Comment: thank you for your attention nullpointer. I have included all the .class files and .jar libraries -- the bin folder, selenium jar, testng jars, json-simple jars, testrail api jar. I'm not sure if any of these libraries depend on some library else that I did not put into my classpath. I mean, I'm using pretty much the same build path in cmd as in eclipse.

Comment: Finally, after days of research, it is solved. The testng library contains two guana related jar files, which are conflicted with the complete guana library that Selenium contains. Remove two guana relate jar files in TestNG solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after days of research, it is solved. The testng library contains two guana related jar files, which are conflicted with the complete guana library that Selenium contains. Remove two guana relate jar files in TestNG solves the problem.